# Which topic does Moveit2 send to robot simulation(rviz, gazebo) to accomplish desired motion execution?

Tags: ros2, moveit, follow-joint-trajectory, jointtrajectory, ros2-control

I want to echo the topic responsible for sending **Joint_trajectory** to the simulation environment (rviz, gazebo). However, I can't read this data. I would like to use this data for sending to the hardware interface for a real robot.

```
OS Version: Ubuntu 22.04
ROS Version: ROS Humble
ROS Packages: 
- Fanuc CRX-10iA/L description, 
- MoveIt2 package via moveit setup assistant
```

Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MoveIt uses joint_trajectory_controller to process the trajectory. I'm not sure now if it uses the topic or the action interface. If the latter is the case, you cannot directly subscribe to a topic.

rviz and gazebo get the data by different means. rviz show the robot_model from tf2-data, which are sent from robot_state_publisher in a typical ros2_control setup. The publisher itself gets joint_states from [joint_state_broadcaster](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_controllers/joint_state_broadcaster/doc/userdoc.html).

Gazebo classic (or gazebo), which is a simulation of the physical system, uses [gazebo_ros2_control](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/gazebo_ros2_control/doc/index.html) or [gz_ros2_control](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/gz_ros2_control/doc/index.html) as hardware component.
Hardware components and ros2_controllers interchange data by means of a shared memory, you cannot directly access data. But joint_trajectory_controller publishes a topic [~/controller_state](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/doc/userdoc.html#publishers) where you can find the data.

To write a driver (called hardware component) with ros2_control framework, have a look at the [demo section](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control_demos/doc/index.html) of the documentation.

Comment: **Thank you** for your well explained response **Mr. Froehlich**. This question came from my old habit :)  I was using [MoveBase](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) package for mobile robot navigation with ROS1. There was a [speed message](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html) generated by the motion planning software which I could echo and I was able to write the necessary driver  to receive speed commands and drive the motor. 

I thought I should do the same for Moveit2 for real robot application. If you have any reference, please feel free to share.

Regards

Comment: i updated the answer above.

Comment: Thank you for the update :)